# how can i check the value stored in -0x14(%ebp) in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I want to know how can I use the print command in gdb to check the value stored in -0x14(%ebp)
I tried to use something like "p $ebp-20, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
p *(int *)($ebp-20)
```

or some variation thereof should do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to use something like "p $ebp-20, but it doesn't work

It *does* work (prints value of `%ebp - 20`), it just doesn't do what you want.

What you want is achieved by the [examine](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#index-examining-memory) command:

```
(gdb) x/x $ebp-20
```